# Bash - How to get string length exclude escape character

Tags: bash, shell, escaping

I wrote a function in my ~/.bashrc to draw a horizontal line based on current terminal width.

```
p_blod=$(tput bold) #use p_orig to reset it
p_red=$(tput setaf 1) #print red
p_blue=$(tput setaf 21) #print blue
p_yellow=$(tput setaf 11) #print yellow
p_orig=$(tput sgr0) #print back original color

vzone() { 
        : "${3?"Usage : vzone '='(separator) y/b(color) b(bold)/nb(not blod) [separator_length_if_need_exclude_escape]"}" #\space or \( 

        local vzone_sep="$1"

        if [[ -z $4 ]]; then
                local t_cols=${#vzone_sep}  #only if the string didn't included escape characters
        else
                local t_cols="$4"
        fi
        
        if [[ "$3" == "b" ]]; then
                printf "%s" "${p_blod}"
        fi

        if [[ "$2" == "y" ]]; then
                printf "%s" "${p_yellow}"
        else
                printf "%s" "${p_blue}"
        fi

        eval printf %.0s"$vzone_sep" $(seq 1 "$((COLUMNS/t_cols))"); echo

        printf "%s" "${p_orig}"
}
```

Then the caller draw a line with:

```
vzone '\(◔‿◔\)\ ♥' y b 7
```

Screenshot:
[image]

As you can see, if i didn't  manually calculate to put 7, the line will wrong because of **${#vzone_sep}** will give me total string included the escape character slash /

Lets me show the narrow example:

```
[xiaobai@xiaobai tmp]$ vzone_sep="\(◔‿◔\)\ ♥"
[xiaobai@xiaobai tmp]$ printf ${#vzone_sep}
10[xiaobai@xiaobai tmp]$
```

What i want is 7, instead of 10 which included escape character. And so the caller don't have to manually count the length minus escape characters before calls my function.

Any help is appreciate.

Comment: It would be simpler to just not use `eval` (and not put escape characters into the string). Why do you feel you need the `eval`?

Comment: @rici Because i can't  call my function without escape character, e.g. vzone '(◔‿◔) ♥' y b will throw syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: You could call the function without escape characters *if you don't use eval*.

Comment: @rici Thanks for pointing it out, because originally i'm not using seq, instead i follow this tutorial, http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/snipplets/print_horizontal_line . But because of i'm not quite understand ${COLUMNS:-$(tput cols)}" stuff that time, so i change to use seq. I'm not realize the eval is not necessary any more and escape is not required. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vzone_sep="\(◔‿◔\)\ ♥"
cleaned="${vzone_sep//\\/}"  # remove all \
printf "%d" "${#cleaned}"
```

Output:

```
7
```